# Flutter FutureBuilder DB query always returns empty snapshot data

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using SQFLite DB with a single table.

This table has one ID record with a true/false flag value of zero or one.

When I update the UI, the DB record value changes to zero if visible or one if hidden.

I was told to use FutureBuilder to extract a database value to manipulate the UI.

The following is the Future DB function that returns a single value:

```
Future<String> read_isFlag() async {
    final myList = await DBHelper.instance.read_isFlag();
    if (myList.isNotEmpty) {
      return myList[0].isFlag.toString();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Empty List');
    }
  }
```

The following is the FutureBuilder code that has Future parameter function above and the snapshot data:

```
SizedBox(width: 100, height:20,child: FutureBuilder<String>(future: read_isFlag(), builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Text('${snapshot.data}');
 } else {
  return Text('Data is Empty');
 }})),
```

Questions:

1. Why is the snapshot data blank?
2. Can I use snapshot in relation to a DB query?
3. What is the relationship between future function and the snapshot data?
4. How do you use snapshot data with a Future function to determine if I should show or hide a UI widget? (note: If the DB value is zero then I will show widget otherwise I will hide the widget)

Thank You

Comment: Please show the FutureBuilder code.  In particular, the "future:" parameter.  I bet I can guess what's wrong with it from that.

Comment: Randal! The FutureBuilder code is shown above. The "future" parameter uses read_isFlag(). Thank You

Comment: Is it specifically "future: read_isFlag()" though?  I still can't tell from what you said.  Presuming so, there's this: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg